# How can I file a bug report on Instagram?

Tags: instagram

I use Instagram on my Android phone and since the last update I can't send photos. I have identified steps on how to reproduce the error and have a very specific bug request to report, including device name and model, app version, OS version, etc., etc.

I just can't find a way to do this. I browsed [their help site](http://help.instagram.com/379302862144995/), and found nowhere to report an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I opened the Insagram help site, it displayed the content in my (non-English) language. I tried searching for more possible solutions, and upon encountering a content available only in English, it offered me to change the site language to English (apparently in a permanent way).

Only after that I was able to browse to [this page](http://help.instagram.com/336211493159529/), that as March 2013 says only:

```
Instagram is crashing 
If your Instagram app is crashing, please file a bug report here.
```

And links to a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=364531043625021) with a bug report form.

There's also an email contact address at the [app page on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android). (The address  - aimed at Android users, obviously - is android-support [AT] instagram [DOT] com). However, messages sent to this address are replied to with an automatic message redirecting to the official help page.